# sending data from one modal to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I used Bootstrap modal.
When I click a link, It will show the bootstrap modal.
Here is the code,

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="view/code-101" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">View</a>
```

It will send code-101 to the server. The server responds with data. And the data will be displayed on the modal.

My problem now is, what about if I would like to send multiple data in another modal?

For Example,
I have a table with columns Title, Description and Action.
In the Action, there will be a link in each row.
If user clicked the link, it will get the corresponding Title and Description of that link. Then another modal will be created, and display the data.

Note: The data is not sent to the server.

Is it possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the data returns from the server set to response to a global javascript variable. In your modals, (re)read the variable as needed. On the server side format the data into a pattern your expect. XML, JSON, etc. Read the global variable in the 2nd modals.